# Можно ли в методе в прототипе функции-конструктора повесить обработчик события, который будет вызывать другой метод из прототипа этого конструктора?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript

Есть функция конструктор, представим, что `buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")` (для примера две кнопки на странице), а `sound` — строка со звуком, который издает животное при нажатии на одну из кнопок.

```
var Animal = function (buttons, sound) {
  this.buttons = buttons;
  this.sound = sound;
};
```

Теперь определяю методы для будущего объекта в прототипе:

```
Animal.prototype.addListeners = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.buttons.length; i++) {
   this.addButtonHandler(button[i]);
  }
};

Animal.prototype.addButtonHandler = function (button) {
 button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  this.makeSound();
 });
};

Animal.prototype.makeSound = function () {
 console.log(this.sound);
};
```

Создаю животного:

```
var buttons = document.querySelector("button");
var cat = new Animal(buttons, "Мяу");
```

В итоге не работает, почему-то не мяукает.
Я думаю что проблема в `addButtonHandler` в том, что я добавляю обработчик события, который вызывает функцию `this.makeSound()`. То есть когда происходит клик по кнопке для обработчика `this.makeSound()` не определено. Не знаю прав ли я, но в любом случае прошу помощи, как это пофиксить, в чем проблема??? Возможно вопрос глупый, простите, только изучаю JS, не все еще понимаю...

```js
var Animal = function(buttons, sound) {
  this.buttons = buttons;
  this.sound = sound;
};

Animal.prototype.addListeners = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.buttons.length; i++) {
    this.addButtonHandler(buttons[i]);
  }
};

Animal.prototype.addButtonHandler = function(button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.makeSound();
  });
};

Animal.prototype.makeSound = function() {
  var element = document.createElement("h1");
  element.textContent = this.sound;
};

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var cat = new Animal(buttons, "Мяу");
cat.addListeners();
```

```html
<button>
Издать звук
</button>

<button>
Издать звук
</button>
```

Comment: эммм а где именно вы вызываете `addListeners`

Comment: у вас в коде несколько ошибок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо элемента выводится `alert`, потому что не понятно куда добавлять элемент. Но если нужно, то используйте `appendChild`

```js
var Animal = function(buttons, sound) {
  this.buttons = buttons;
  this.sound = sound;
  // не было вызова this.addListeners
  this.addListeners();
};

Animal.prototype.addListeners = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.buttons.length; i++) {
    // тут вы к button[i] обращались, что не правильно
    // this.addButtonHandler(button[i]);
    this.addButtonHandler(this.buttons[i]);
  }
};

Animal.prototype.addButtonHandler = function(button) {
  // тут вы потеряли контекст this.makeSound не определена
  // button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  //  this.makeSound();
  // });
  // стрелочная функция сохранит контекст
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    this.makeSound();
  });
};

Animal.prototype.makeSound = function() {
  // var element = document.createElement("h1");
  // element.textContent = this.sound;
  // куда вы добавляете этот элемент? Никуда
  alert(this.sound);
};

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var cat = new Animal(buttons, "Мяу");
```

```html
<button>
Издать звук
</button>

<button>
Издать звук
</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, извиняюсь за многочисленные ошибки, очень быстро писал код, но основная проблема в моем проекте была как раз в потери контекста.